# Google App Invites: iOS App and Android app with different package names/bundle IDs - how can they be linked with goo.gl/App Invites?

Tags: android, ios, google-play-services, google-url-shortener, google-app-invites

I an app for both iOS and Android that I need to link via App Invites - but they have different package names/bundle IDs that represent the same service - how do I link them with goo.gl / the app-invite system?

The android package name differs from the iOS bundle ID because the Android key was lost by the previous developer, unfortunately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can send invites between android and iOS. They are linked using the developer console (console.developers.google.com). Both the android app and the iOS app need to be in the same console project. If there is only one of each, then when sending across platforms it's unambiguous which to choose and you can just send an invite. The app invite service will send the proper short links(goo.gl/...) to install/launch the proper app per platform.

If there are multiple instances of a iOS and/or Android apps in the console project, then the client ID must be sent with the invite using Api call setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication(...) so that app invite service knows which of the console apps should be selected.

For same platform, i.e. android to android, the app selected will match the app that sent the invitation, so same platform is not ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. I am trying to add the AppInvite to my Android app. I noticed that emails were not sent out, but text messages did. Also the URL received to my friend's Android phone (via a text message) pointed to some page that showed an error message. Does this feature work only if the app is downloaded from the app store?

Comment: I found the answer to my previous comment: Yes, the app needs to be uploaded to the Google Play first. I uploaded it as a Beta Test and I was able to receive invites via email and text messages both, on both iOS and Android. Very impressed with how simple this implementation worked.